# DTD validation for small and simple xml

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to build a small validation for this XML

```
<adr>
  <parameters>
    <type><text>work</text></type>
    <label><text>Simon Perreault 2875 boul. Laurier, suite D2-630 Quebec, QC, Canada G1V 2M2</text></label>
  </parameters>
  <pobox/>
  <ext/>
  <street>2875 boul. Laurier, suite D2-630</street>
  <locality>Quebec</locality>
  <region>QC</region>
  <code>G1V 2M2</code>
  <country>Canada</country>
</adr>
```

Considering `pobox` has two attributes `cod` and `region`, what am I missing with this DTD ? Can anyone help me?

```
<?mlx version ="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ADR [

<!ELEMENT ADR (PARAMETERS, POBOX, EXT, STREET, LOCALITY, REGION, CODE, COUNTRY)>
<!ELEMENT PARAMETERS (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT POBOX (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT EXT (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT STREET (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT LOCALITY (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT REGION (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CODE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT COUNTRY (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST POBOX COD CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST POBOX REGION CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Comment: Just a comment: Your processing-instruction on top of the DTD is wrong (`<?mlx version ="1.0"?>`). Maybe fixing it would improve something.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I noticed:

- Like mentioned in a comment, your XML declaration is invalid. It probably doesn't cause any issues because the parser doesn't know what `mlx` means and it's treated as a normal processing instruction.
- Case matters. If you have an element `adr` it shouldn't be declared as `ADR`.
- In the XML, `parameters` has two child elements, but is declared to only allow `#PCDATA`.
- It's not wrong, but it is easier to read if you only have one `ATTLIST` declaration for an element.
- Usually if you have a separate DTD file, the DOCTYPE declaration is not used in it. The DOCTYPE is usually in the XML instance itself. Not sure if that's going to cause you problems or not (probably depends on how you're validating the XML). It might also be in the same file, but you've split it up in the question.

Here's an updated version of your DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE adr [
<!ELEMENT adr (parameters, pobox, ext, street, locality, region, code, country)>
<!ELEMENT parameters (type, label)>
<!ELEMENT type (text)>
<!ELEMENT label (text)>
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pobox (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST pobox 
    cod    CDATA #IMPLIED
    region CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT ext (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT locality (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT region (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT code (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)>
]>
```